# Specifing part of Spring context properties from JUnit test files

Tags: spring, junit4

I have multiple mock implementations of a bean, that bean is referenced as beanA. Mock's reference names is let say: beanAMock1, beanAMock2... beanAMockN.

In context file I am aliasing beanA reference according to context placeholder beanAImplementation:

```
<alias name="${beanAImplementation}" alias="beanA"/>
```

Also there other beans (beanB, beanC...) that have mock implementations like this. And I have a number test suits that utilizing theirs specific sets of beanA, beanB... implementations.

All beans have default values for theirs switching placeholders that is specified in property file included from context.

I am looking for a ways to change part of bean's implementations per test suit.

I know three ways to do this:

1) create additional context file for each test suit that will load required properties from separate property files - this way requires creation of two additional files per test suite (context,  property).

2) create profile for each test suite with aliases definitions. As I understand this requires providing aliases for each bean within per each profile - while I am having a default set of beans implementations.

3) create context within test suite manually and override required properties - with this I need to write many of the code within test suite.

Is there another ways? (may be like #3 but working with SpringJUnit4ClassRunner or its subclasses and if it will be possible just to provide required properties within annotations - it seems to be a best approach)

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem by subclassing SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and overriding its 
TestContextManager createTestContextManager(Class clazz) method. This method accepts Class object of test suite and is called before context creation. So it is possible to read additional annotations from test suite class and set system properties that will substitute corresponding placeholders during context creation.